# Why react-jwt token is not working with jsonwebtoken?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

I have a restify server authenticated with jsonwebtoken. In the frontend I used `react-jwt` for taking some data from the token.
Here is the code:

```js
// Private route
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import { loggedIn } from "../adapter/auth";

const PrivateRoute: React.FC<{
  component: React.FC;
  path: string;
  exact: boolean;
}> = ({ path, exact, component }) => {
  if (!loggedIn()) return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  else {
    return <Route path={path} exact={exact} component={component} />;
  }
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

```js
// auth check
import xhr from "./xhr";
import { isExpired, decodeToken } from "react-jwt";

interface User {
  _id?: string;
  fullname?: string;
  email?: string;
}

const token: any = localStorage.getItem("jwt_token");
export const user: User | null = decodeToken(token);

export const loggedIn = () => {
  return token && !isExpired(token);
};
```

But whenever I use `isExpired` method, on the back-end showing this error:

```sh
F:\projects\node-projects\restify-api\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:37
      if (err) throw err;
               ^
JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (F:\projects\node-projects\restify-api\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:63:17)
    at async (F:\projects\node-projects\restify-api\index.js:20:22)
    at nextTick (F:\projects\node-projects\restify-api\node_modules\restify\lib\chain.js:167:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

Comment: *JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed* - it's either not a JWT or you got extra characters in the string variable that should hold the token, e.g. `Bearer eyJ...` or similar.  But without seeing you code and token it's not really answerable.

Comment: I just added the codes. Please have a look.